# Basic Linked List C implementation

Tags: c, linked-list

I've written a singly-linked list of characters. This is my 3rd C program and I'd like some feedback on what I can improve on in any aspect whatsoever.

If you'd prefer to look at the repo directly it's here:

https://github.com/JosephSBoyle/LinkedList

Thanks in advance for your time :D

linked_list.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>

// define the node struct here so we can use it within it's own definition
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    /* A node in a linked list */
    char item;  // character at this node
    Node *next; // pointer to the next node
};

size_t NODE_SIZE = sizeof(Node);

/* Create a new list */
Node* list();

/* Destruct a list, freeing it's memory */
void free_list(Node* sentinel);

/* Add an element to the end of a list */
void add(Node* sentinel, char item);

/** Delete an element from a list.
 * @returns true if the operation succeeded, false if there is the list is shorter than
 * the supplied index argument.
 */
bool del(Node* sentinel, size_t idx);

/* Replace the value stored by the node at idx. */
bool replace(Node* sentinel, size_t idx, char item);

/* Get the length of a list */
size_t len(Node* sentinel);

/* Peak the idx'th node, or the last node if there are fewer than
   idx elements in the list. */
Node* peak(Node* sentinel, size_t idx);

/* Pretty-print a list */
void print(Node* sentinel);

/* Print a list as a contiguous string */
void pstring(Node* sentinel);
```

linked_list.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <assert.h>

Node* list(){
    // create a 'sentinel node'.
    Node* sentinel = (Node*)malloc(NODE_SIZE);
    sentinel->next = NULL;
    sentinel->item = '\0';
    return sentinel;
}

Node* peak(Node* sentinel, size_t idx){
    Node* node = sentinel;

    // compare to idx + 1, since we want our peak to be zero-indexed
    // and we have a sentinel node
    for (size_t i=0; i != idx+1; i++){
        if (node->next == NULL){
            // return the sentinel node as there are fewer than idx elements in the list
            return sentinel;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    return node;
}

void free_list(Node* sentinel){
    // traverse each node in order and free it's memory.
    size_t i = 0;
    do {
        i++;
        free(sentinel);
        sentinel = sentinel->next;
    } while (sentinel->next != NULL);
}

void add(Node* sentinel, char item){
    // instantiate a new node
    Node* new_node = (Node*)malloc(NODE_SIZE);
    new_node->item = item;

    // traverse each node
    while (true){
        if(sentinel->next == NULL){
            // replace the last node with our new node.
            sentinel->next = new_node;
            break;
        } else {
            // point to the next node
            sentinel = sentinel->next;
        }
    }
}

bool del(Node* sentinel, size_t idx){
    // TODO find a way to leverage peak to simplify this
    for (size_t i=0; i != idx; i++){
        if (!sentinel){
            return false;
        }
        sentinel = sentinel->next;
    }
    if (sentinel->next){
        Node* index_node_ptr = sentinel->next;
        if (index_node_ptr->next){
            sentinel->next = index_node_ptr->next;
        } else {
            free(index_node_ptr);
            sentinel->next = NULL;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

bool replace(Node* sentinel, size_t idx, char item){
    Node* node = peak(sentinel, idx);
    // check if the sentinel and the peaked node are the same
    if (sentinel == node){
        return false;
    } else {
        node->item = item;
        return true;
    }

}
size_t len(Node* sentinel){
    Node* current_node = sentinel;
    size_t nodes = 0;
    while (true){
        // Check if we're at the final node.
        if(current_node->next == NULL){
            return nodes;
        }
        nodes++;
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
}

void print(Node* sentinel){
    printf("[");
    while (sentinel->next != NULL){
        sentinel = sentinel->next;
        printf("'%c',", sentinel->item);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

void pstring(Node* sentinel){
    while (sentinel->next != NULL){
        sentinel = sentinel->next;
        printf("%c", sentinel->item);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* Tests */
void main(){
    Node* sentinel = list();

    add(sentinel, 'h');
    add(sentinel, 'e');
    add(sentinel, 'l');
    add(sentinel, 'l');
    add(sentinel, 'o');
    print(sentinel);

    replace(sentinel, 4, '0');
    pstring(sentinel);

    // check that deleting works for a valid index
    assert(del(sentinel, 4));
    // and fails when that index becomes invalid.
    assert(!del(sentinel, 4));

    // check peaking an invalid index returns the sentinel node
    assert(sentinel == peak(sentinel, 4));

    pstring(sentinel);
    free_list(sentinel);
}
```

Running the code (tested on ubuntu linux):

```bash
$ gcc -o run linked_list.c
$ ./run
```

Comment: 'peek', not 'peak', perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall: a good code for a "my 3rd C program".

Good formatting

Good documentation in .h file.  (Perhaps a bit more to detail expectational cases.)

**No need for object `NODE_SIZE`**

Simply use `#define NODE_SIZE sizeof(Node)`.

As is, each .c file that includes `linked_list.h` makes an object `NODE_SIZE`, eventually causing multiple definitions.  `.h` files should not *define* any objects.

**Information hiding**

The *definition* of `struct Node` belongs in the .c file.  Users of these functions never need to see the internals.  Move `struct Node { ...};` to the .c file.

**Name space**

Code uses common names like `Node, list, add, del, peak, print, ...` which are likely to collide with the rest of code.  Consider a common prefix instead. `linked_list_add, linked_list_del, linked_list_peek, ...`.

**Empty arguments in a declaration**

No arguments in a declaration matches any argument set.  Use `void`.

```
// Node* list();
Node* list(void);
```

This differs from a function *definition*.  This distinction may change in the next C version.

**`add()` may fail**

Since `add()` calls `malloc()`, that allocation may fail.  Consider returning an error flag here too.

```
// void add(Node* sentinel, char item);
bool add(Node* sentinel, char item);
```

**What if empty list?**

`peak()` does not describe return value in this case.

**Exercise `*.h` include independence**

In `linked_list.c`, include its companion .h file first to help validate that no `<xx.h>` files are needed.

```
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <string.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include "linked_list.h"
// #include <assert.h>

#include "linked_list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
```

**Use `const`**

For function that do not change the `*sentinel`, use `const`.  This increase functions applicability, conveys code's intent better and allows for some optimizations not seen by lesser compilers.

```
// Node* peak(Node* sentinel, size_t idx)
Node* peak(const Node* sentinel, size_t idx)
```

**`NULL` argument**

`list()` may fail to allocate, and should be re-written to return `NULL` in that case.

`free_list(Node* sentinel)` should check if `sentianl == NULL` and does nothing - just like `free(NULL)` is OK.  This simplifies calling code's error handling.

**Cast not needed**

In C, a cast is not needed to convert a `void *` to an `object *`.  Further I recommend to size to the reference object and not the type.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Check allocation success.

```
// Node* sentinel = (Node*)malloc(NODE_SIZE);
Node* sentinel = malloc(sizeof sentinel[0]);
if (sentinel == NULL) {
  return NULL;
}
```

**Test code**

Consider moving `main()` test code to a 3rd file instead of `linked_list.c` to allow other application to use/link linked_list.c and not collide with `main()`.

**`peek()` return**

I'd expect `peak()` to return the `item` and not `struct Node`.  Or to provide an error return, consider returning a pointer to the item and `NULL` on error (e.g. empty list) or some other interface - anything that does not oblige the user from needing to see `Node` internals.

**Code guards**

linked_list.h deserves code guards.

Comment: thank you for your kind feedback! 

I have adopted the changes you recommended :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a use after free in `free_list`.

None of the functions check that the `sentinel` argument is not null.

`add` doesn't insure that the new node's `next` is null.

I think `del` fails if you give it the index of the last item. It definitely doesn't have a `return` call in that path.